# How to create a bootable Windows 11 installation USB drive (for a PC) on macOS and avoid the error "media driver on your computer is missing"?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, bootable-disk

I bought a PC without OS and I want to install Windows 11 on it. But I only have a Mac and a flash drive at hand. Neither my Mac nor the PC have a DVD drive.

I cannot use Microsoft's official *Media Creation Tool*
(`mediacreationtool.exe`) for copying the Windows 11 image to the USB drive -- there's no Mac version available.

I tried to *Restore* the ISO to the USB drive in *Disk Utility*, but it resulted in the error message "Restore process has failed".

I tried to *Create a Windows 10 or later install disk* in *Boot Camp Assistant*, but after booting on USB, the Windows installer could not open the partition and reported "A media driver on your computer is missing". Disconnecting and reconnecting the USB drive did not help.

I tried with [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher) but I got the same result.

How can I copy the Win11 ISO file to the USB drive so that the installation works flawlessly on the PC?

Note: I'm using macOS Big Sur on an Intel Mac.

Answer (score 7):

[Jensd's guide](https://jensd.be/1740/windows/create-a-bootable-windows-11-installation-usb-on-macos) did the trick for me (Thanks!)

TLDR:

- In *Disk Utility*, *Erase* the USB drive with *Format*: **MS-DOS (FAT)** and *Scheme*: **Master Boot Record**.
- Mount the [Win11 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) and copy all files except `source/install.wim` (too big for FAT32)
- Install [Wimlib](https://wimlib.net): `brew install wimlib`
- Copy the remaining file while splitting it in FAT32-compatible chunks: `wimlib-imagex split /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/sources/install.wim /Volumes/WINUSB/sources/install.swm 4000`

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks

Comment: why not just use exfat?